# mock method from child class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have parent class

```
class StatsPeriod::Base
  def merge(data)
    to_range.inject({}) do |result, date|
      result[date] = data[date] || 0
      result
    end.to_a
  end
end
```

and this is my spec

```
require "rails_helper"

describe StatsPeriod::Base do
  let(:data) { { "20160604" => 1, "20160601" => 2 } }
  let(:range_data) do
    [
      "20160528",
      "20160529",
      "20160530",
      "20160531",
      "20160601",
      "20160602",
      "20160603",
      "20160604"
    ]
  end

  describe "#merge" do
    let(:stats) do
      [
        ["20160528", 0],
        ["20160529", 0],
        ["20160530", 0],
        ["20160531", 0],
        ["20160601", 2],
        ["20160602", 0],
        ["20160603", 0],
        ["20160604", 1]
      ]
    end

    it "returns hash with stats" do
      expect(described_class.new.merge(data)).to eq(stats)
    end
  end
end
```

How I can mock method `to_range` which exist only in child class and returns `range_data`
or maybe I should mock child class and expect something like ChildClass.merge(data) but

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it simply this?

```
  it "returns hash with stats" do
      fred=described_class.new
      allow(fred).to receive(:to_range) { range_data}
      expect(.merge(data)).to eq(stats)
  end
```

Comment: #<StatsPeriod::Base:0x007f9741bbb478> does not implement: to_range

Answer (score 0):

Ruby + monkey-patching = win :)

If you want, you could just open up the class and add an implementation of the method for the sake of testing. To prevent global scope, probably best to use refinements
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html

```
module M
  refine StatsPeriod::Base do
    def to_range
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

then you can call

```
using M
```

inside your spec to bring the monkey patch into scope?